# Picking image is not work in LG Optimus

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery, lg

I am developing some Android apps. I want to **select picture in gallery and crop it** at **Fragment**. This code is worked at Sony, Samsung, Nexus, AOSP but it doesn't works at LG Optimus phone(ex. Optimus G Pro). It doesn't return when cropping image is done, and it not call **onActivityResult** callback. Can you help this problem please? The sample code is here.

It's requesting intent code.

```
    getView().findViewById(R.id.info_img).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
```

It's **onActivityResult** Callback. It's Overrided at Fragment Class.

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        try {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        }

        if (bitmap != null){
            // TODO : It must Worked at here!!
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's just a LG framework's bug. Don't mind at this.